# Using Javascript to display current tab in navbar

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net

I have a bootstrap side navbar setup on my site. I want to show the user what tabe has been selected by maintaining the active css property. Here is what the side navbar looks like:

```
    <div style="font-size: 80%; background-color: #ffffff; width: 15%;" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li >
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LB_MainPage" CssClass="activeBtn active" runat="server" OnClick="LB_MainPage_Click">Ticket Books Home</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
        <li >
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LB_IssueTicket" CssClass="activeBtn" runat="server" OnClick="LB_IssueTicket_Click">Issue Ticket Book</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
        <li >
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LB_Change_TicketBooks" CssClass="activeBtn" runat="server" OnClick="LB_Change_TicketBooks_Click" >Change Ticket Books</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
        <li >
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LB_TicketBook_Reports" CssClass="activeBtn" runat="server" OnClick="LB_TicketBook_Reports_Click">Search Ticket Books</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
        <li >
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LB_MissingTickets" CssClass="activeBtn" runat="server" OnClick="LB_MissingTickets_Click">Custom Reports</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
        <li >
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LB_AddVoidTicket" CssClass="activeBtn" runat="server" OnClick="LB_AddVoidTicket_Click" >Add Void Ticket</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
        <li >
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LB_VoidTickets" CssClass="activeBtn" runat="server" OnClick="LB_VoidTickets_Click" >Void Tickets</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to apply the CSS styling as such:

```
        li .activeBtn {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .activeBtn.active {
        color: purple;
        border-bottom: solid;
    }
```

When a `LinkButton` is clicked I want to change the `LinkButton` to active and reset all of the other buttons back to not active. This is the jQuery function that I have in my MasterPage to do so:

```
$(function () {
          $(".activeBtn").click(function () {
          // remove classes from all 
          $(".activeBtn").removeClass("active");
           // add class to the one we clicked 
          $(this).addClass("active");
          console.log("this is a test log");
          });
          });
```

the code is working properly in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/hwcgynr0/2/). I believe the reason that it is not working because I have a multi-view on my page. When the LinkButton is clicked I change the view in the multi-view.

Any ideas why this would not be working like it is in the jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/hwcgynr0/4/
Add class to clicked element, then find siblings and remove their's active class

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.activeBtn', function () {
        $(this).addClass('active').closest('li').siblings().children().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: This acts in the same manner as before. When I click the LinkButton you can tell it tries to work, but it is almost like something is overriding it.

Comment: If code working properly at jsfiddle, where's the problem? in your application? You did not noticed this fact. If so, than means something interfere with that code

Comment: My code is exactly the same as the jsFiddle. Although I am using a multiview, and the linkbuttons are chaging the multi-view. I think that may be where the problem is.